# variable scopes in python vs ruby blocks

Tags: python, ruby, loops

I am a completely new to Python so bear with me. In ruby I can write:

```
test = []
10.times do |i|
 test.push(i)
end
put test.to_s
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Python I am trying to retrieve a similar result:

```
test = []
for i in range(10):
  test.append(i)

print test
>>> [0]
>>> [0, 1]
>>> [0, 1, 2]
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3]
...
```

So with ruby I can write a block and append to a variable outside the scope of that block. Is there a similar way to do this with python?

Comment: At the end of the python for loop you just wrote you have achieved your goal as described.  What is the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: The output you produced indicates that you are using the `print` statement **inside** the loop, not outside.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying. This is Python 2.6. Also, how would I go about using the print statement out of the loop to just call the final 'test' result?

Comment: @KSFT: Python 2, since `print` is used as a statement and no syntax error was raised.

Comment: @Josh: By not indenting it to the same level as `test.append(i)`. In the Python interactive interpreter, add a blank line after the `test.append()` call to signal the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: The docs have a page with a bunch of information about this kind of stuff: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

The comments are right; what you've written is correct, although you can just write `test = range(10)` if you want that list. If you want to do something more complicated with the elements, you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), something like `test = [i for i in range(10)]` in this case.

Comment: In fact, you can just do `list(range(10))` because a range object is a generator.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Did you read my answer? I mentioned that. In Python 2, at least, `range` returns a list object.

Comment: My bad I didn't see it originally.

Comment: Your range() example is equivalent to `(0...10).to_a ` in ruby, and your list comprehension is similar to ruby's `select()`, neither of which is what the op asked about--although there are some interesting differences between a block's scope in ruby and a list comprehensions scope in python...none of which you addressed.

Answer (score 0):

> In ruby I can write:
>
> ```
> test = []
>
> 10.times do |i|
>  test.push(i)
> end
>
> put test.to_s  #Note, in ruby you would write: p test
> => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> ```

A rough equivalent in python would be:

```
test = []

def block(i):
    test.append(i)


for i in range(10):
    block(i)

print test

--output:--
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

See python's scope rules [here](http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/05/12/a-beginners-guide-to-pythons-namespaces-scope-resolution-and-the-legb-rule/).

Comment: The only difference between this and Josh's attempt is that this defines a completely unnecessary function.

Comment: @KSFT, The title of the post was: *variable scopes in python vs ruby blocks*. A ruby block equates to a python function. Then the op stated: *with ruby I can write a block and append to a variable outside the scope of that block. Is there a similar way to do this with python?* My example shows a python function appending to a variable outside the function scope(LEGB!).  *The only difference between this and Josh's attempt is that this defines a completely unnecessary function.*--Are you unaware that python's for loops do not create a new scope?

Comment: No, I am not unaware of that.

Comment: *"A ruby block equates to a python function"* -> Well, sort of, but  not really; a block has some special semantics, and it's not a "first-class" function, like in Python ... In any case, translating Ruby to Python 1-to-1 is a wrong idea, since the languages use different methods to solve things.

Comment: I don't understand how your first comments are relevant(you can add: *blocks are not objects* if you are trying to compile a list of irrelevant trivia), and for your last comment: the op did not ask how to create a series of numbers in python--the op asked about how the scopes in ruby and python compare.  In ruby, you would just create a series of numbers like this:  `(0..9).to_a`, and if the op asked how to translate that code to python, then the answer would be `range(10)`.